# Error loading library (ggplot2) & (tibble) & (tidyverse) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tibble

I was trying to load the following and retrieved this error.  I also tried loading tibble since the error messages references it but have a similar error message.  I have tried installing the packages and uninstalling as well to no conclusion. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘tibble.so’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘$.tbl_df’, ‘[.tbl_df’, ‘[[.tbl_df’, ‘row.names<-.tbl_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_df’, ‘as_data_frame.NULL’, ‘as_data_frame.data.frame’, ‘as_data_frame.default’, ‘as_data_frame.list’, ‘as_data_frame.matrix’, ‘as_data_frame.table’, ‘as_data_frame.tbl_df’, ‘as_tibble.NULL’, ‘as_tibble.data.frame’, ‘as_tibble.default’, ‘as_tibble.list’, ‘as_tibble.matrix’, ‘as_tibble.poly’, ‘as_tibble.table’, ‘as_tibble.tbl_df’, ‘as_tibble.ts’, ‘check_names_before_after.character’, ‘check_names_before_after.default’, ‘check_names_df.character’, ‘check_names_df.default’, ‘check_names_df.logical’, ‘check_names_df.numeric’, ‘format.tbl’, ‘format.tbl_df’, ‘format.trunc_mat’, ‘format_v.character’, ‘format_v.default’, ‘format_v.list’, ‘glimpse.data.frame’, ‘glimpse.default’, ‘glimpse.tbl’, ‘print.tbl’, ‘print.tbl_df’, ‘print.trunc_mat’, ‘quote_n.cha [... truncated] 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

> library(tibble)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘tibble.so’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘$.tbl_df’, ‘[.tbl_df’, ‘[[.tbl_df’, ‘row.names<-.tbl_df’, ‘as.data.frame.tbl_df’, ‘as_data_frame.NULL’, ‘as_data_frame.data.frame’, ‘as_data_frame.default’, ‘as_data_frame.list’, ‘as_data_frame.matrix’, ‘as_data_frame.table’, ‘as_data_frame.tbl_df’, ‘as_tibble.NULL’, ‘as_tibble.data.frame’, ‘as_tibble.default’, ‘as_tibble.list’, ‘as_tibble.matrix’, ‘as_tibble.poly’, ‘as_tibble.table’, ‘as_tibble.tbl_df’, ‘as_tibble.ts’, ‘check_names_before_after.character’, ‘check_names_before_after.default’, ‘check_names_df.character’, ‘check_names_df.default’, ‘check_names_df.logical’, ‘check_names_df.numeric’, ‘format.tbl’, ‘format.tbl_df’, ‘format.trunc_mat’, ‘format_v.character’, ‘format_v.default’, ‘format_v.list’, ‘glimpse.data.frame’, ‘glimpse.default’, ‘glimpse.tbl’, ‘print.tbl’, ‘print.tbl_df’, ‘print.trunc_mat’, ‘quote_n.cha [... truncated] 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tibble’
```

When i check the installed packages, i see the following ggplot2 references;

```
ggplot2           "ggplot2"
ggplot2           "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library" "2.2.1"  
ggplot2           NA 
ggplot2           "R (>= 3.1)"  
ggplot2           "digest, grid, gtable (>= 0.1.1), MASS, plyr (>= 1.7.1),\nreshape2, scales (>= 0.4.1), stats, tibble, lazyeval"  
ggplot2           NA    
ggplot2           "covr, ggplot2movies, hexbin, Hmisc, lattice, mapproj, maps,\nmaptools, mgcv, multc
ggplot2           "sp"
ggplot2           "GPL-2 | file LICENSE"                   NA
ggplot2           NA                    NA      NA     "no"             "3.3.2"
```

Thanks!

Comment: strange, did you try reinstalling these packages?

Comment: I did and yet nothing has changed

Comment: Restart R then try: `install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies=TRUE, repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")`

Comment: You might need to update R as 3.3 is too old. Latest version is 3.5.1

Comment: Thank you, I will try those suggestions and let you know.